# Is the `\` character escaping or becoming part of my ssh key password

Tags: bash, escape-characters

If I do:

```
ssh-keygen -N password123\$ -f bobskeys
```

Is `\` escaping the `$` character or becoming part of the password?

Or rather, will `bash` be doing any escaping before `ssh-keygen` gets the password value?

Do I need to escape the `$` character?

I'm running Centos 5.5 x64 and bash 3.2.25

Comment: and now we all know your password... ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you type:

```
ssh-keygen -N password123\$ -f bobskeys
```

the shell will execute ssh-keygen with arguments `-N` `password123$` `-f` and `bobskeys`.

If you want to pass `password123\$` as an argument you need to single-quote it:

```
ssh-keygen -N 'password123\$' -f bobskeys
```

or backslash the backslash:

```
ssh-keygen -N password123\\$ -f bobskeys
```

Otherwise the `ssh-keygen` process will not see the backslash.

Answer (score -2):

from the `ssh-keygen` man page:

> A passphrase is similar to a password, except it can be a phrase with a series of words, punctuation, numbers, whitespace, or any string of  characters  you  want.
>          Good  passphrases  are 10-30 characters long, are not simple sentences or otherwise easily guessable (English prose has only 1-2 bits of entropy per character, and provides
>          very bad passphrases), and contain a mix of upper and lowercase letters, numbers, and non-alphanumeric characters.

since the `-N` argument is to create a new passphrase, the `\` sign is part of the paraphrase.

Comment: So bash won't be doing any escaping before ssh-keygen gets the password value?

Comment: Actually, that might depend on the shell. It appears to me that both bash (4.1) and zsh (4.3.11) will change `\$` to `$` as part of parsing. (At least, `echo -E \$ | od -c` will show no backslash, where as single-quoting it would.)